# How to handle an array with multiple keys and integers that needs to be combined?

Tags: php, arrays

I know the title is a bit vague but I didn't know how else to word it.  I have this array that contains names and numbers.  What I am trying to do is to combine the same names but add up the numbers for that name.

So here is the array:

```
array (array[0] => ([tom] => 4) array[1] => ([mike] => 6) array[2] => ([tom] => 6) array[3] => ([alice] => 9) array[4] => ([alice] => 10) array[5] => ([mike] => 3))
```

*pretty sure I typed it wrong on top but I think you get what I mean?

So I am not sure the best way to combine the names to be unique but at the same time add all the numbers up for that name as well so the end result looks like this.

```
array ([tom] => 10 [mike] => 9 [alice] => 19)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your array contains multiple keys with same name? In my opinion it's not even possible...

Comment: Ah...sorry, I mis the part where there is an index on top of that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from here:

```
$source = array(
    array('tom' => 4),
    array('mike' => 6),
    array('tom' => 6),
    array('alice' => 9),
    array('alice' => 10),
    array('mike' => 3)
);

$result = array_fill_keys(array_map("key",$source),0);

foreach ($source as $person)
    foreach ($person as $name => $value)
        $result[$name] += $value;

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: This throws multiple warnings since you didn't set the keys before. As suggested in my queue edit, replace $result by `$result = array_fill_keys(array_map("key",$source),0);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$source = array(
    array('tom' => 4),
    array('mike' => 6),
    array('tom' => 6),
    array('alice' => 9),
    array('alice' => 10),
    array('mike' => 3)
);

$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $source);
echo '1st step: '; print_r($result);

$result = array_map('array_sum', $result);
echo '2nd step: '; print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
1st step: Array
(
    [tom] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 6
        )

    [mike] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 3
        )

    [alice] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 10
        )

)
2nd step: Array
(
    [tom] => 10
    [mike] => 9
    [alice] => 19
)
```